# Receive data from one form to another in the form with Post method and Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried to get the data with the post method in the processing file but I couldn't.
I need to receive the data by POST method an show my data in process.php
Remember that my inputs are not in the form tag.
I just wanted to move to the relevant page with the window.location.href code.
I think when the user is transferred to the processing page by JavaScript.
The post data is lost

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#smp").click(function(event){
         var name = $('#name').val();
         $.ajax({

                  url: "process.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data:name,
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "process.php";
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // the error will accure if process.php did not return a valid response (return)
                            alert(data);
                            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
                            $('#result').html('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                            console.log('textStatus:');
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log('errorThrown:');
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="form"><label id="icon" for="name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

        <div class="btn-block">

          <button id="smp" type="submit" href="/">Submit</button>
        </div></div>
```

my php file
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f379f5e2662300270c64ad867316ca268dd91640

Comment: What is the error inside the ajax call? I feel like there should be a type error before that

Comment: @Patch Not show results for POST methods

Comment: Why do you want to send it as JSON request? it seems pointless, the value and the key are the same 

I'd recommend sending it like `data:name` I am pretty sure that the error is the data that you are sending

Comment: If you want to send the form as `ajax`  instead of the normal submit you need to prevent the form's default submit behavior with `event.preventDefault();`. As a side note, the php part is very strange. You determine weather your variable was send through get or post by evaluating its content. That can be any string in both cases though.

Comment: @Lapskaus I didn't even noticed he is doing form there is no need for that. He is checking if the user clicked on the button in JQuery the form is useless. It's sending 2 POST requests to `process.php`

Comment: @Lapskaus i just to get  my data to process page and need after click redirect to process.php and show my data which I received from Index.php with POST method

Comment: @Patch Because I need to receive the data by POST method , no POST is set, I changed the key but it doesn't work

Comment: @MmdRasoulSh it still doesn't explain the 2 requests that you are doing are you doing form or ajax there is no reason to do both. you can get the data and then redirect you can get the value of the input at the function like you are doing please post an updated question with the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explained what is going on in the code in a comment. there is no reason for you to send a JSON requests you are sending the same values in the key and the value it's pointless.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#smp").click(function(event){
         var name = $('#name').val();
         $.ajax({

                  url: "process.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        dataType: 'text',
                        data:{"name" : name}, // here you are sending process.php name too. if it returns something then it should go th the success function and redirect.
                        success: function (data) {
                            window.location.href = "process.php?name=" + name; // if the function returned something then it will redirect it to "process.php?name=" + name
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // the error will accure if process.php did not return a valid response (return)
                            alert(data);
                            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
                            $('#result').html('<p>status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>' + jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                            console.log('jqXHR:');
                            console.log(jqXHR);
                            console.log('textStatus:');
                            console.log(textStatus);
                            console.log('errorThrown:');
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });

        });
    });
```

now, your HTML code should not include `form` there is just no reason to send it! you are just sending 2 requests with the same data so I'd replace it with this code:

```
<label id="icon" for="name"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

        <div class="btn-block">

          <button id="smp" type="submit" href="/">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

important to add: if you insist on leaving the form request without redirect you could use  `.preventDefault();`

Comment: tnx you but Maybe I didn't mean it to you.
I edited my question.how to use this data with POST method in process.php? i echo this but notwork : echo $_POST['name'];

Comment: Why do you need to send data if you are only using it in javascript in the ajax request you need I am using flask but you don't need to echo 'name` you need to echo the `request.data()` or something like that

Comment: Look at my updated answer, try this code and try that with `echo  $_GET['name'];` if the POST dosen't work

Comment: i use a api its fields must be filled with data coming from the form in index.php I can do it with the GET method, but for security I want to use the post method

Comment: @MmdRasoulSh Do it with post but try the code that I updated

Comment: I think when the user is transferred to the processing page by JavaScript.
The post data is lost

Comment: why won't you just redirect it in HTML or just redirect it in javascript when the user clicks on the submit

Answer (score 1):

In order to submit your form with ajax you would need to prevent the default submit behavior of the form with `preventDefault()`.

In your code you would do it like so:

```
$("#smp").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default submit
  var name = $('#name').val();
  ...
```

---

**Some side notes:**

1. Instead of using the `click event` of the submit button you should rather use the `submit event` of the form itself and instead of gathering the input data you want to send manually you should use the given jQuery functions to do so. You could for example add an ID to your form:

`<form action="process.php" method="post" id="myForm">`

and then

```
$("#myForm").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var $form = $(this); // the form that gets submitted
  var url = $form.attr('action'); // get the url from the forms action attribute
  var data = $form.serialize(); // get the form as url encoded string
  var method = $form.attr('method');
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: method,
    data: data,
    success: function ( response ) {
      window.location.href = url + '?' + data;
    },
});
```

By doing so you now can add input fields to your form and dont have to add them to your data and url string by hand.

2. Lets say you enter 'tony' in your input and hit `submit`. Your code now does this:

   1. Posting `{"name": "tony"}` via ajax to the process.php
   2. The process.php echos `Good its POST` and is done
   3. You receive that echo with the `response` in your `success` callback
   4. You immediatly redirect to the `process.php` page with the get paramter `name=tony`
   5. Your process.php gets called and echos nothing because your `$user_g` variable has the value `tony`, which is not in your conditions

So you wont see the output of your `Good its POST` anywhere, because you immediatly redirect.

Comment: tnx you but This code didn't work for me
Maybe I didn't mean it to you.
I edited my question.

Comment: Please look at my sidenotes again, especially at the second part where i explain what your code does at the moment. If you simply want to use POST and process the data wiht your `process.php` ajax actually complicates things. Just remove the whole ajax event handler enter 'toni' and submit your form, you should see a white page with `Good its POST`

Comment: tnx , i use beforeSend in ajax how implement its without ajax?

Comment: It's lieterally as simple as just removing the whole javascript code. Given that you still have the `<form>` tag wrapped around your input and submit button as you had in your original question.